# Azure Function with TDS(Tabular Data Stream) and MFA enabled Authentication

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-functions, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I have a C# console App which uses the below connection string and it works fine, when i run it it asks for the password and once authenticated it works perfectly and i can access dynamics crm online database. However now i want to move the code and use Azure Function, when in Visual Studio it works same as in Console App but the interactive Azure AD authentication won't work when it is published to Azure. Does anybody has any idea how to implement this. I can't find any article where i can see any Demo or documentation.

`string ConnectionStringTDS = @"Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};SERVER=*******.crm.dynamics.com;DATABASE=******;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryInteractive;UID=XRMDe**@****.com";`

I have enabled TDS to access database using SQL Query. MFA is enabled in my account. Using service principal.

Answer (score 0):

you need Application user i.e OAuth2 authentication to connect with Dynamics. with username and password and login prompt is not the way.

enabling TDS endpoint will not help you in connection via c# on Azure functions

[Take a look at this article.](https://softchief.com/2021/08/03/connect-dynamics-365-from-console-c-application-in-mfa-enabled-access-using-client-secret-and-azure-client-id/)

1. Create App Registration in Azure AD (clinet ID and secret)
2. Create Application user in Dynamics.(assign correct security role)
3. use this clientId and secret to get authentication Token in C#.
4. use .netcore SDK for Dynamics to perform CURD operations

[.net core example](https://dynamicsblog365.wordpress.com/2020/12/31/connect-dynamics-crm-cds-using-net-core/)

Comment: Thanks @AnkUser, I am actually using the above described method in my project but with this we can only use fetchXML to interact with DB however i want to use SQL Queries due to performance issue and FetchXML query limitation in a special case where i need it. Otherwise it was just working fine.

Comment: you can use [query expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/developer/data-platform/org-service/build-queries-with-queryexpression) as well In addition you can use early bound and [linq query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customerengagement/on-premises/developer/org-service/sample-complex-linq-queries?view=op-9-1) which will look like your sql statement.